# how to list stores using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 pages Home and Listing. currently, I am able to list all the stores (based on selction) but when I try to use the stores with services, I end up with wrong data. I want help in sorting this out.

expectation: In Home, I am selecting the Store(S_Store) and the Services (S_Services) on clicking go button, the listing page should show all the stores and the services that I have selected. Below is the sample code that I am using

```
home page
<div  ng-controller="SamsungServicesCtrl">
     <ion-content> 
           <li class="item item-checkbox"  ng-repeat="item in items" >
             <img src="{{item.icon}}"  style="float:left;height:30px;width:30px;padding-right:5px;" > 
             <label  class="checkbox checkbox-energized"  >
               <input type="checkbox"  style="float:right;"   ng-model="item.selected"  >
             </label>
             {{item.name}}
              <p style="font-size:10px;  padding-left:0px;">  {{item.subname}}</p>
           </li>
           <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-full button-energized"  value="submit" ng-click="check()">Apply
            </button>
           </div>

    </ion-content>
</div>
<script>
.controller('SamsungServicesCtrl', function ($scope,$filter,$location) {
       var service = ["Regular Service", "Settings Faults", "Software Faults", "Hardware Faults"];
       var services = ["General services", "If a phone doesn’t switch-on, it is called a dead phone, SIM card does not get detected", "Hardware Faults"];
       var icons = ["images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg"];
         $scope.items= [] ;
            for(var i=0;i<service.length;i++)
                {
                    var modal = {
                        name:service[i],
                        subname:services[i],
                        icon:icons[i],
                        selected:false
                      }; 

                    $scope.items.push(modal);        
                }
                scope.check = function()
                {
                      var checkedItems = [];
                       for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++){
                          if($scope.items[i].selected){
                             checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                             }
                            }
                   //$location.path('menulisting/listing');

        //i have checked Regular Service, Settings Faults
        $location.path('listing').search({model: 'nokia', items:checkedItems});
                 }

    })  
</script>
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper" >
         <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" >
    </label>
</div>
<div class="list card"  data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers |  filter:query ">
    <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
         <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
         <p>{{dealer.S_Address.area}} {{dealer.S_Address.city}}</p> 
         <p>{{dealer.S_Services}}</p>
    </div>   
</div>

listing page
<script>
listing controller
.controller('ListingCtrl', [
'$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter','$ionicPopover','$ionicLoading',
function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicPopover, $ionicLoading) {
$scope.dealers = [{
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults,Interior faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "siva@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "mobile service center",
        S_Services: "overall faults,mobile faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"}
    ]


            var filter = $location.search().model;
            var items = $location.search().items;
            console.log(filter);
            //nokia
            console.log(items);
            //Regular Service,Hardware Faults
            $scope.dealers=[];
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                var temp=data[i].S_Store.split(',');
                for(var j=0;j<temp.length:j++){
                    if(temp[j]===filter)
                       $scope.dealers.push(data[i]);
                    }
                }


}])
</script>
```

i have given my code full code.i need to display list of data where ever nokia match with S_Store and Regular Service, Settings Faults match with S_Services in dealers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But i just remove some of the template/div elements and changes are visible.
refer to fiddle that i have created. *`http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/700/`*

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SamsungServicesCtrl">
        <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper"> <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="list card" ng-repeat="dealer in dealers | filter:query">
            <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
                 <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
                <p>{{dealer.S_Address.area}} {{dealer.S_Address.city}}</p>
                <p>{{dealer.S_Services}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])

function SamsungServicesCtrl($scope, $filter, $location) {
    var service = ["Regular Service", "Settings Faults", "Software Faults", "Hardware Faults"];
    var services = ["General services", "If a phone doesn’t switch-on, it is called a dead phone, SIM card does not get detected", "Hardware Faults"];
    var icons = ["images/arrow.svg", "images/arrow.svg", "images/arrow.svg"];
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < service.length; i++) {
        var modal = {
            name: service[i],
            subname: services[i],
            icon: icons[i],
            selected: false
        };
        $scope.items.push(modal);
    }
    $scope.dealers = [{
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
    }]
    $scope.check = function () {
        var checkedItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
                checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
            }
        }
        //$location.path('menulisting/listing');
        //i have checked Regular Service, Settings Faults
        $location.path('menulisting/listing').search({
            model: 'nokia',
            items: checkedItems
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if check this Regular Service,mobile faults condition its not working

Comment: this is wrong answer please check my controller and html first

Comment: Please provide the complete code. It is too clumsy to understand from the given sample code